# AVAudioPlayerNode produces click / popping noise when using stop

Tags: ios, noise, avaudioplayernode

I need some help here. I am converting part of my IOS app code from OpenAL to AVAudioEngine since OpenAL does not seem to work well in IOS 9. I am having the following issue. When I call the stop method for a AVAudioPlayerNode, I get a very audible click / popping noise. This happens in the device and in the simulator.

I tried with different audio files and formats just in case but that is not the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

AVAudioEngine is going to play the audio buffer as it is. If the audio begins or ends abruptly you will hear a clicking sound. The only solution is to have the audio fade in/out, either by manipulating samples at the buffer level or by timing the volume changes on the mixer node to coincide with playback.